# Load test in Visual Studio 2013, do I have to install agent on remote server?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, load-testing

I'm having an application on a test server that I don't have the source code for. Can i remotely load test it with visual studio 2013? It means that I can't install any agents on the test server.

Answer (score 0):

You can remotely test it from your machine using Visual Studio against the test server. If you want to run it remotely from another server other than your test server, you would need to install the test controller/agent on that server to run it remotely from there.

Here is a good article on it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243155.aspx

If it is publicly accessible, you can run the test from Visual Studio Online without installing any test agents.
http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/load-test-your-app-vs.aspx

Mike